# Not able to edit table in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, primary-key, auto-increment

Not able to edit existing table in phpmyadmin. I tried setting `id` as `primary key` and also `auto increment` but it throws **error** in both cases even though there is no other column which is being set as primary key or auto increment.

Comment: what is the error you getting and why you are not able to set primary key?

Comment: it says "duplicate entry '33' for key primary"

Comment: do have all values in the column unique which you want to make the primary key? can you please share the schema.

Comment: @Bhansa  thanks it worked. i checked that while importing tables all data was created with duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first edit the entries in the table, so that there are no duplicate rows with the same id. The error message you receive says what the problem is: `"duplicate entry '33' for key primary"`. So there is atleast two entries with the same id number, 33. After you have fixed those problems, then you should be allowed to set the property primary key on `id`.

Primary key implies that all columns that builds up the primary key are unique when combined, and if only one column, then all those entries in that columnd needs to be unique.